# Using streams to sum a collection of immutable `Duration` objects, in Java

Tags: java, java-stream, immutability

The [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class built into Java 8 and later represents a span of time unattached to the timeline on the scale of hour-minutes-seconds. The class offers a `plus` method to sum two such spans of time.

The *java.time* classes use immutable objects. So the [`Duration::plus`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#plus(java.time.Duration)) method returns a new third `Duration` object as a result rather than altering (mutating) either of the input objects.

The conventional syntax to sum a collection of `Duration` objects would be the following.

```
Duration total = Duration.ZERO;
for ( Duration duration : durations )
{
    total = total.plus( duration );
}
```

Can streams be used in place of this `for` loop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## `Stream#reduce`

This can be achieved using the overloaded [`Stream#reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) method that accepts an identity:

```
durations.stream().reduce(Duration.ZERO, Duration::plus)
```

The following snippet provides an example:

```
var durations = List.of(Duration.ofDays(1), Duration.ofHours(1));
System.out.println(durations.stream().reduce(Duration.ZERO, Duration::plus));
```

As expected, the output is:

```
PT25H
```

Comment: Feel free to accept [Naman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60816300/7294647) since he sniped me by about 10 seconds :P

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can make use of `reduce` operation with identity element as

```
Duration total = durations.stream()
        .reduce(Duration.ZERO, Duration::plus);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fully working example with sample inputs. You need to use the reduce function in java streams. Here is a [short tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce) that I used.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class DurationTest {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        List<Duration> durations = IntStream
                .rangeClosed(1, 10)
                .mapToObj( n -> Duration.ofSeconds(n) )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        int sumOfSeconds = (10 * (1 + 10) ) / 2;

        Duration total = durations.stream().reduce( Duration.ZERO, (t, d) -> t = t.plus(d) );
        System.out.printf("actual = %s, expected = %s", total.getSeconds(), sumOfSeconds);
    }
}
```